# How to keep only the text after a specific tag and insert to other rows 0

Tags: r, quanteda

Data

```
data.frame(id = c(1, 2), text = c("something here <h1>my text</h1> also <h1>Keep it</h1>", "<h1>title</h1> another here"))
```

How is it possible to keep after this tag `<h1>my text</h1>` the text until to find the next start of a  tag and if this not exist in the row insert 0

Example output

```
data.frame(id = c(1, 2), text = c("also", 0))
```

Comment: I can see you've asked several variants of questions concerning manipulation with these tags - you should accept the ones you prefer as answers.

Answer (score 1):

In regex you can use lookaheads and lookbehinds, see [this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more info. With naming the data `df`:

```
df$text <- str_extract(df$text, pattern = "(?<=</h1>)(.*)(?=<h1>)")
ifelse(is.na(df$text), "0", trimws(df$text))

[1] "also" "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in **quanteda** using several `corpus_select()` calls:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2),
  text = c(
    "something here <h1>my text</h1> also <h1>Keep it</h1>",
    "<h1>title</h1> another here"
  )
)

library("quanteda", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
## Package version: 2.1.1

corp <- df %>%
  corpus(docid_field = "id") %>%
  corpus_segment("<h1>my text</h1>", pattern_position = "before") %>%
  corpus_segment("<h1>", pattern_position = "after")
```

Now we can get your 0s from merging this with the sequence of IDs, and converting any non-matches (`NA`s) to 0:

```r
library("dplyr", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
convert(corp, to = "data.frame") %>%
  rename(id = doc_id) %>%
  select(id, text) %>%
  mutate(id = as.integer(id)) %>%
  right_join(data.frame(id = 1:2)) %>%
  tidyr::replace_na(list(text = 0))
## Joining, by = "id"
##   id text
## 1  1 also
## 2  2    0
```